# remove() not working(as intended) in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am starting this specific part of a project that involves the user clicking a button with class: add_button to create a div that is the file for storing information, all the functions in the user created files are functional except for one,

```
function delete_file() {
    const deleted_file = event.target.parentNode;
    deleted_file.remove();
  }
```

It turns out during testing, it only deletes the latest div/file that was created, I later made it so that it doesn't have remove() but instead change the border which works for some reason.The full code is here.

```js
//Create New File
function create_file() {
  const file_query = document.getElementsByClassName("file_query")[0];
  const file_base = document.createElement("div");
  const file_name = document.createElement("input");
  const ok_button = document.createElement("button");
  const open_button = document.createElement("button");
  const rename_button = document.createElement("button");
  const delete_button = document.createElement("button");
  file_base.setAttribute("style", "margin-left: 28pc; margin-top: 4pc;  width: 66pc;  height: 5pc;  border: 5px outset grey;  background-color: rgb(182, 180, 180);");
  file_base.setAttribute("class", "file_base_t");
  file_name.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute;  margin-top: 1.45pc;  margin-left: 1pc;  height: 30px;  width: 340px;");
  file_name.setAttribute("class", "id_collector");
  file_name.setAttribute("placeholder", "File Name...");
  file_name.addEventListener("input", no_border)
  file_base.appendChild(file_name);
  ok_button.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute;  font-family: fantasy; margin-top: 1.4pc;  margin-left: 22.5pc;  height: 35.5px;  width: 50px;  border-top-right-radius: 25%;  border-bottom-right-radius: 25%;  background-color: #90ee90;");
  ok_button.setAttribute("class", "ok_button_t");
  ok_button.textContent = "Y";
  ok_button.addEventListener("click", addId);
  file_base.appendChild(ok_button);
  open_button.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute;  font-family: fantasy; margin-left: 9pc;  margin-top: 19px;  height: 50px;  width: 70px;  background-color: #90ee90;  display: none;  pointer-events: none;");
  open_button.setAttribute("class", "open_button_t");
  open_button.textContent = "Open";
  open_button.addEventListener("click", open_dictionary); 
  file_base.appendChild(open_button);
  rename_button.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute;  font-family: fantasy; margin-left: 52pc;  margin-top: 17px;  height: 50px;  width: 70px;  background-color: #90ee90;  display: none;  pointer-events: none;");
  rename_button.setAttribute("class", "rename_button_t");
  rename_button.textContent = "Rename";
  rename_button.addEventListener("click", rename_id);
  file_base.appendChild(rename_button);
  delete_button.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute; font-family: fantasy; margin-left: 60pc;width: 70px;height: 50px; margin-top: 16px;  background-color: #90ee90;");
  delete_button.setAttribute("class", "delete_button_t");
  delete_button.textContent = "Delete";
  delete_button.addEventListener("click", delete_file); 
  file_base.appendChild(delete_button);
  file_query.appendChild(file_base);
}

function addId() {
  const id_parent = event.target.parentNode;
  const y_no = id_parent.querySelector(":nth-child(2)")
  const id_input = id_parent.querySelector(":nth-child(1)");
  const open_ok = id_parent.querySelector(":nth-child(3)");
  const rename_ok = id_parent.querySelector(":nth-child(4)");
  let id_value = id_input.value;
  if (id_value == "") {
    id_input.style.border = "3px solid red";
  } else {
    id_parent.setAttribute("id", id_value);
    id_input.style.display = "none";
    id_input.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    y_no.style.display = "none";
    y_no.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    open_ok.style.display = "block";
    open_ok.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
    rename_ok.style.display = "block";
    rename_ok.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
  }
}

function open_dictionary() {
    window.location.replace("http://127.0.0.1:5500/LanguageStorage.html")
}

function rename_id() {
    const renamed_button = event.target.parentNode;
    const open_no = renamed_button.querySelector(":nth-child(3)");
    const rename_no = renamed_button.querySelector(":nth-child(4)");
    const ok_ok = renamed_button.querySelector(":nth-child(2)");
    const input_ok = renamed_button.querySelector(":nth-child(1)");
    open_no.style.display = "none";
    open_no.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    rename_no.style.display = "none";
    rename_no.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    ok_ok.style.display = "block";
    ok_ok.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
    input_ok.style.display = "block";
    input_ok.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
}

function delete_file() {
    const deleted_file = event.target.parentNode;
    deleted_file.remove();
  }
  
function no_border() {
    event.target.parentNode.querySelector(":nth-child(1)").style.border = "none";
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.top_nav {
    position: sticky;
    background-color: mediumspringgreen;
    width: 200pc;
    height: 6pc;
    margin-left: -34px;
    margin-top: -35px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid yellow;
  }
  
.main_title {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 50px;
    color: yellow;
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 200%;
    font-family: fantasy;
  }
  .word {
    position: relative;
    top: -4pc;
    left: 400px;
    color: yellow;
    z-index: 5;
    font-size: 150%;
    font-family: fantasy;
  }
  .wordt {
    position: relative;
    top: -4pc;
    left: 400px;
    color: yellow;
    z-index: 5;
    font-size: 150%;
    font-family: fantasy;
  }
  .wordg {
    position: relative;
    top: -9pc;
    left: 550px;
    color: yellow;
    z-index: 5;
    font-size: 150%;
    font-family: fantasy;
  }
  .wordi {
    position: relative;
    top: -14pc;
    transform: rotate(2deg);
    left: 700px;
    color: yellow;
    z-index: 5;
    font-size: 150%;
    font-family: fantasy;
    width: 12px;
    transform: rotate(90deg)
  }
  .wordj {
    position: relative;
    top: -15pc;
    left: 900px;
    color: yellow;
    z-index: 5;
    font-size: 150%;
    font-family: fantasy;
  }
  .wordp {
    position: relative;
    top: -20.7pc;
    left: 800px;
    color: yellow;
    z-index: 5;
    font-size: 150%;
    font-family: fantasy;
    width: 12px;
    transform: rotate(90deg)
  }
  .words {
    position: relative;
    top: -24.5pc;
    left: 1050px;
    color: yellow;
    z-index: 5;
    font-size: 150%;
    font-family: fantasy;
    width: 12px;
  }
  .folder_searcher {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
    left: 64pc;
    top: -25.6pc;
    width: 23pc;
    height: 35px;
    border: 3px solid black;
  }
  .search_button_text {
    position: relative;
    top: -29.4pc;
    left: 95.7pc;
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 90%;
    font-family: fantasy;
  }
  .search_button {
    position: relative;
    top: -25.6pc;
    border-top-right-radius: 25%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25%;
    right: -63.5pc;
    background-color: #90ee90;
    width: 50px;
    height: 43px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
.top_nav:hover .search_button {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}
.scroll_image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 6.4pc;
  height: 193px;
  width: 150pc;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(107, 87, 88, 0.7), rgba(253, 253, 253, 0.9)), url("https://indianapublicmedia.org/large-images/amos-images/isaiah-scroll.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  overflow:scroll;
}
.seperator {
  margin-top: -12.2pc;
  height: 12px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(178, 255, 89, 0.5), rgba(37, 58, 124, 0.5));
}
.about_us {
  color: white;
  font-size: 200%;
  font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  margin-left: 45pc;
}
.about_us_paragraph {
  color: white;
  font-size: 200%;
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 90pc;
  font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
.add_bar {
  margin-top: 13pc;
  margin-left: -12px;
  width: 230pc;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(233, 232, 232);
  border-bottom: 3px solid grey;
}
.add_button {
  position: relative;
  top: -46px;
  margin-left: 78pc;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.content:hover .add_button {
  background-color: grey;
}
.num_file_text {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -28.5pc;
  top: 23pc;
  color: rgb(14, 204, 204);
  font-size: 150%;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
.number_list {
  margin-top: 21.5pc;
  margin-left: 13pc;
  width: 350px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 12%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.number_list_r {
  height: 90px;
  padding-top: 1px;
}
.starting_num {
  position: relative;
  top: -12px;
}
.file_query {
  border: 1px solid rgb(214, 212, 212);
  margin-top: 0.8pc;
  margin-left: -12pc;
  width: 250pc;
  height: 290pc;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(255, 255, 255), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTHCBd8-57JaK_VsnXDjo61aL-3AkwM7TpLN-w7-Vaa&s");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}
.filebase:hover .okbutton {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}
.filebase:hover .openbutton {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}
.filebase:hover .deletebutton {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}
.filebase:hover .renamebutton {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}
button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section class="top_nav">
        <p class="main_title"><u>LanguageMaker3000</u></p>
        <p class="word"><u>Robosteyr</u></p>
        <p class="wordt"><u>derewaq</u></p>
        <p class="wordg"><u>mmuytr</u></p>
        <p class="wordi"><u>sacter</u></p>
        <p class="wordj"><u>sabbydabby</u></p>
        <p class="wordp"><u>cocou</u></p>
        <p class="words"><u>piuyttt</u></p>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search Files..." class="folder_searcher">
        <button type="button" class="search_button">Y</button>
        <div class="scroll_image">
            <p class="about_us"><u>About Us</u></p>
            <p class="about_us_paragraph">Hi! I'm Matt and I proudly present the LanguageMaker3000(Although there aren't 2999 more versions of this)!Language has been around for more than 1 million years and
                is the root of every famous civilizations such as Ancient Egypt and Greece.This is a goofy website that allows you to create your own languages!:)
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="seperator"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="content">
        <div class="add_bar"></div>
        <button class="add_button" onclick="create_file()"><b>+</b></button>
        <p class="num_file_text">Current Files:</p>
        <div class="number_list">
            <div class="number_list_r">
                <p class="starting_num">0</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="file_query">
        </div>
    </section>
```

I will be happy to accept any solutions/alternatives to my issue.

Comment: Congrats on you picking up coding early mate! Personally, I would be attempting to reference the exact element you want to remove by passing the `id` through to the function, then using `.remove()`  on that

Comment: Can't repro. For me, using your snippet if I create three sections, type AAA in the first, BBB, and CCC in the second and third, then click the [Delete] button of the second one (BBB), I correctly get AAA and BBB sections remaining. Could it be that because the sections below move up to fill the space of the deleted section, you thought you weren't deleting the correct one?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't delete the correct one as it only the latest div created which happens to be CCC, i can try so alternatives I though of such as making it just have no display and no pointerEvents and make it's width to noothing so that the elements have space to move up or take the more straight-forward way and just make it so that you can only delete the div if the user manually creates an ID.

Comment: also thx darren for the idea